# Angular JS breaking two way binding on isolate scope when binding to a primitive and using ng-include to dynamically load a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

I have a bit of a strange scenario that is a little different to the other childscope and two way binding issues I have seen on Stackoverflow.

I have a field generation directive that receives a configuration object and some data and dynamically creates the correct type of field on screen and populates the data.

**directive.js**

.directive('myField', function () {

```
var stringTemplate = "scripts/directives/templates/my-string.tpl.html";
var textTemplate = "scripts/directives/templates/my-text.tpl.html";
var selectTemplate = "scripts/directives/templates/my-select.tpl.html";

var linker = function ($scope, elem, attrs) {

  // Function to dynamically select the correct template
  $scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
    var template = '';

    if ($scope.options) {
      if ($scope.options.optionList) {
        template = selectTemplate;
      } else {
        switch ($scope.options.type) {
          case 'String':
            template = stringTemplate;
            break;
          case 'Text':
            template = textTemplate;
            break;
        }
      }
      return template;
    }
  };
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    options: '=',
    data: '=',
    fieldName: '@',
    fieldWidth: '@',
    labelWidth: '@',
  },
  link: linker,
  template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()"/>'
}
});
```

I then have the corresponding template... I'm showing just the string template in this case.

**my-string.tpl.html**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label for="{{fieldName}}" class="{{labelWidth}}">
  {{options.label}}
  </label>
  <div class="{{fieldWidth}}">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="{{fieldName}}" placeholder="{{options.watermark}}" ng-model="data" tooltip="{{options.tipText}}" ng-disabled="options.editable === false">
  </div>
</div>
```

An example of how this might then be used would be

**controller.js**

```
$scope.person.firstName = "John";
$scope.person.lastName = "Doe";
$scope.options.person.firstName.type = "String";
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <my-field options="options.person.firstName" data="person.firstName" field-name="firstName" label-width="small" field-width="medium"></my-field>
```

The problem is the usual one, my-field directive has an isolated scope with a "data" property that is two-way bound to the controller. Because I am then using ng-include to dynamically load the correct template I am creating a further child scope that due to prototypical inheritance still populates correctly as it doesn't have its own data property so reaches to the parent. However when I modify the field, a shadow property is created on my child scope called data that doesn't propagate upwards the way that two way binding should.

I hope you are still with me

**controller > my-field**

ng-include causes the following scopes to exist

**controller > my-field > ng-include**

From reading around I understand that what I need to do to rectify this is pass an object rather than a primitive, however as there is effectively an intermediate layer between my controller and my final directive this is not straightforward.

I thought about changing the isolate scope in my-field to look like this

```
scope: {
  ....
  data: {value: '=data'}    
  ....
}
```

and then updating the template to refer to the object

**my-string.tpl.html**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label for="{{fieldName}}" class="{{labelWidth}}">
  {{options.label}}
  </label>
  <div class="{{fieldWidth}}">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="{{fieldName}}" placeholder="{{options.watermark}}" **ng-model="data.value"** tooltip="{{options.tipText}}" ng-disabled="options.editable === false">
  </div>
</div>
```

but this kills angular.

I have successfully got it to work by reaching back to the controller scope for binding by using

```
ng-model="$parent.$parent.data"
```

but I am not really happy with this as a solution as A it is ugly and B it involves knowing the depth of scope you are at which could vary.

Really stumped with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you avoid ng-include by compiling your selected template to the correct scope within your link function?

Comment: Hi Phil, yes I did try this but it triggered some sort of infinite compile loop on the fields. In the linker function I had something like this `elem.load(getTemplateUrl(),function(){
      $compile(elem)($scope);
     });`

Comment: Try `$compile(elem.contents())($scope)` instead - you don't want to compile the container again.

Comment: Tried this yesterday, same issue. It seems to get stuck in an infinite compile loop for all the different my-field instances. Not sure if it is related to the elem.load statement. Itself but I ran this `elem.load(getTemplateUrl(),function(){ $compile(elem.contents())($scope); });`